# Переход на PHP 7 Как переделать из preg_replace в preg_replace_callback?

Tags: php, php7

Здравствуйте.
Перевожу сайты на PHP и там в шаблонизаторах используется такая конструкция.
Как мне ее переделать в preg_replace_callback? Уже какие варианты только не перепробывал

```
$in["#\\[index:(.+?)\\](.*?)\\[/index\\]#ies"] = "indexShow('\\1', '\\2')";
$in["#\\[modules:(.+?):(.+?)](.*?)\\[/modules]#ies"] = "modulesShow('\\1', '\\2', '\\3')";

$in["#\\[guest](.*?)\\[/guest]#ies"] =  "checkGuest('\\1')";
$in["#\\[user](.*?)\\[/user]#ies"] =  "checkUser('\\1')";
$in["#\\[title:(.*?)]#ies"] =  "\$this->preTitle('\\1');";
$in["#\\[open](.*?)\\[/open]#ies"] =  "\$this->preOpen('\\1');";
$in["#\\[userinfo:(.*?)]#ies"] =  "\$this->ustinf('\\1')";

$text = preg_replace(array_keys($in), array_values($in), $str);
```

Помогите пожалуйста передать из preg_replace в preg_replace_callback, уже разные варианты делал, не помогает.

Comment: собственно, какова цель перевода в другую функцию?

Comment: @teran, модификатор `e`.

Comment: Цель перевода из-за того что PHP 7 ругается,  preg_replace устарела и говорит используйте preg_replace_callback

Comment: @ДенисЗахаренко, устарела не функция `preg_replace()`, а то что я написал в комментарии выше.

Comment: @Visman вот и мне он не понравился :)

Answer (score 1):

Делаете так для php7:

```
$in["#\[index:(.+?)\](.*?)\[/index\]#is"] = function($matches) {
    return indexShow($matches[1], $matches[2]);
};
...
$text = preg_replace_callback_array(array_keys($in), array_values($in), $str);
```

Comment: Век живи - век учись. Запихнуть регулярку ключом массива - это... надо уметь придумать.